# What are dangerous motherboard operating temperatures?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, gpu, cooling, temperature

There are five motherboard temperature sensors for my PC, according to HW Monitor.

Two of these, called TZ00 and TZ01, are always at 28C and 30C respectively, no matter what. I am inclined to believe that these are bugged readings, since my ambient temp itself is often above 30C.

The other three readings are referred to as TMPIN0, TMPIN1 and TMPIN2. I have no idea what TMPIN0 measures, but TMPIN1 seems to somewhat correlate with my GPU temperature and TMPIN2 definitely matches with the temperature of my CPU.

Under 100% GPU load (with corresponding 85% CPU load), the temperature readings for my PC's motherboard are as follows:

TMPIN0 - 50C  //(Idle = 38C)

TMPIN1 - 64C  //(Idle = 45C)

TMPIN2 - 70C  //(Idle = 43C)

[When CPU is stress tested to 100% load, TMPIN2 reading reaches 74C, with TMPIN1 reading reaching a max of 49C]

I would like to ask very simply, are these still safe (albeit high) operating temperatures when at 100% GPU/CPU load, or are these very dangerous temperatures?

At what point should I be concerned with the temperatures of my motherboard? I have a Dell 0XR1GT motherboard.

Mind, I live on the equator, so I have ambient temps of 29C at night and 34C during the day on average.

Thank you!

Edit: To add, when at 100% GPU load my GPU temperature reading itself is 80C, and under 100% CPU load, my CPU package temperature reading is up to 75C. However, the focus of my question is still on the motherboard temperature reading, since I have found the GPU/CPU readings themselves while high are still acceptable.

Comment: All those readings are well within specification of the hardware involved.  Dell designed your hardware to operate as it was sold without overheating, if it overheated, you would know.

Answer (score 0):

The detailed supported operating temperature can be found in the componenents' technical specifications.

Modern chips are made to support higher temperatures than they did 15-20 years ago, and usually handle temperatures up to 100C (which is critical).

I wouldn't worry if a server reached a temperature of 80C when fully loaded, so you should probably not worry about it either.

That said, better air conditioning could improve the life expectancy of some of your components, especially hard drives.

Comment: Indeed, I do not have air-conditioning where the PC is located.


But to clarify, when you say life expectancy, is it an appreciable amount? My PC is currently 3.5 years old, everything in there is from the time I got it except the GPU which is new. 


I did have a HDD crash on me just a month ago (3.5 year old), but I was told it wasn't due to the temperatures inside the case (~42C HDD temps on average).

Comment: @hsjj3 For reasonable temperature ranges, there is a fairly solid inverse correlation between operating temperature and hard disk drive lifespan (drive running hotter dies sooner), but in a sample of one there are other factors which are likely to be much more significant, including handling and random, statistical errors. I would say that a consumer HDD lasting 3½ years isn't particularly surprising either way; I would consider that a reasonably expected life span. Consider that most consumer rotational HDDs are warrantied for only 1-3 years; it's rare to see five-year warranties among those.